# How to prevent Angular from forcing its update

Tags: angular, versioning

I have a contractor full stack developer who insists that Angular forced an update on the development environment to the latest version, which after several weeks has not been fixed. Hopefully it may soon. This was an unplanned change, which has been devastating, especially as she is still charging to fix it.

Q. Is there a way to prevent forced updates, so this doesn't happen in future? If so, what is it or am I being taken for a ride by the contractor?

Comment: Even if there was an auto upgrade it should usually be no problem to downgrade in case of troubles in s working system. 10 minutes of work max XD

Comment: Thanks - that upsets the hell out me at the same time because all comments pretty much point to the case that there is no plausible reason this issue has befallen us and prolonged. It looks more like stubbornness to treat it as a personal challenge rather than think of the greater good. The impression I'm being told is that the impact is far-reaching. Also that this has affected numerous people/organisations -I seriously thing I'm being played.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **No** there is no such thing as forced updates by an external package publisher.

### Overview of NPM

NPM is the package manager used by most NodeJS projects. It can be configured in the `package.json` to download JavaScript libraries that match a version condition. Such as the latest version, the latest in development or an explicit version only (never download anything other than that).

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

### Overview of Bower

Bower is an alternative package manager for projects that just want to track JavaScript libraries. There is a `bower.json` which uses a version matching condition similar to NPM.

https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md

## Angular updates

> I have a contractor full stack developer who insists that Angular forced an update on the development environment to the latest version, which after several weeks has not been fixed.

As a developer myself, I would advise that you're misinterpreting what the developer is telling you. Try asking for specific details such as which package, which version and ask the question "why" a lot.

Keep in mind that the Angular 2 project is not finished, and often releases breaking changes. Anyone developing an app with that version can expect lengthy delays trying to maintain compatibility with each new release.

The Angular 1 project is stable. There has not been a breaking API release in the past year.

For the Angular 1.x project you can read release notes here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

For the Angular 2.x project you can read release notes here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> This was an unplanned change, which has been devastating, especially as she is still charging to fix it.

No software development project goes smoothly. Expect costly delays and problems. If you find some thing like this devastating then you are in the wrong business. The contractor will just go work somewhere else that is better managed, and you'll go out of business.

Responsibility for a project is on the owner. The success of a project is on the owner. The contractor is just passing by temporarily to do some programming. If you want to defer responsibility and reduce the risk of failure. You need to spend more money on a more senior and experienced contractor. Thus, the end result is the same. Spend more on this contractor to fix the issue, or spend more on a new contractor who doesn't create these issues.

> Q. Is there a way to prevent forced updates, so this doesn't happen in future? If so, what is it or am I being taken for a ride by the contractor?

Yes, it's called backups. When was the last time you received a backup of the source code developed by this contractor, and have you been keeping backups? Where is your source code now? Do you use a Git repository? Are you using an issue tracker to keep track of changes?

Instead of trying to fix the problem for the contractor. You should protect yourself by taking more control of the source code and the project.

Comment: Thank you. Very informative. I certainly will ask a lot of "why" questions. I'll clarify a few things, however. The way it was put to me was that Angular had updated when the build was made and it caused a plethora of issues that needed to be fixed. I was told that development had to halt until it was fixed. There was no mention of the option to revert to a backup -'apparently' regularly run. Devastating as it has consumed the dev budget and opportunity windows due to missed deadlines. There is GIT and Jira in use. The developer is very senior and experienced, hence why I ask if I'm being had

Comment: @M.Mathers this website is for programming questions. I recommend that you go to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ and post a question about measuring the trust of a contractor and what you're experiencing with this contractor.